# When can I split a matrix into a sum of a commuting and non commuting matrix relative to another?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a non commuting matrix product $AX$ , what conditions on the product do I need to be able to write $X=Y+Y'$ with the properties

1. $$ AY=YA$$
2. $$ AY' \neq Y'A$$

With $Y \neq 0$ and $X \neq 0 $ and also we can't decompose $Y'$ further into a sum of commuting and non commuting matrix except the trivial case.

Intuitively speaking I want to factor the matrix X into a commuting and non commuting part. A further property I'd like on the non commuting part is that it shouldn't be factorable again into a sum of non commuting and commuting matrix except the case where commuting matrix is identity.

This is a purely hypothetical question I came up with, and I really don't think I have the sufficient linear algebra knowledge to even put an attempt at this. If there is a theorem which discusses this question, then I'll accept an answer giving that.

Comment: If $AX \ne XA$, then just let $Y=0$ (the zero matrix) and $Y'=X$.

Comment: Good point, I am searching for non trivial cases @GeoffreyTrang

Comment: I would think that you would want to specify some condition on $Y'$  to insure uniqueness, like maybe an orthogonality condition.

Comment: I think you need to work harder to say what you mean by "trivial cases".  Is $Y=I$ trivial? Is it trivial if $Y$ commutes with every $A$?

Comment: The set of all matrices commuting with $A$ is a vector subspace (of the space of matrices), and if the field is $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ (or skew field $\Bbb H$) you should be able to define $Y$ as the projection of $X$ onto this subspace as the "best" candidate. (Or you could consider the space of polynomials in $A$ and/or its adjoint.)

Comment: I see what you meant @MJD please see the edit now. I want the matrix to be factored over addition into a commuting and non commuting where the non commuting part isn't further factorable

Comment: Hi! I changed the hypothesis a bit. Could you check now  @runway44

Comment: Every noncommuting matrix can be decomposed into a nonzero commutating matrix and another nonzero noncommuting matrix. Just pick any commuting matrix you want, and let the noncommuting matrix be the difference.

Comment: I don't think you can choose a non commuting matrix sometimes. Take for example A *[ 0 1 , 1 0]

Comment: Very interesting question... hmm anon did give the answer: the set of matrices commuting with A is indeed a subspace, even an algebra (which contains/equal??? the polynomials in A). And since any subspace of a vector space admits a supplementary, the whole space is indeed a direct sum.